# How can I use lex to identify strings other than the quotation marks?

Tags: string, lex

Real lex rookie . I'm trying to use regular expression , to identify strings in a `printf()` such as `printf("hello world!");` , but the best result is just "hello world!" , and I don't want the double quotation marks , just hello world! How should I do ?

The regex so far is: `("\"")(.)*("\"")`

Comment: Please show us your regex!

Comment: Thanks for your comment！also a real StackOverflow  rookie(lol) || it just ("\"")(.)*("\"") . I have tried a lot of other messy versions, and it's already the best ... that's a part of my first Compilation Principle experiment course , and I've been entangled in this problem for almost a week . I really want to solve this weird problem, and it makes me feel like lex has not provided a relevant way to "remove" the content for auxiliary recognition.

Comment: That regex will fail if you have two string literals on the same line. Do you see why?

Comment: thanks for your help! Probably understand... it will match the farthest symbol, which is the longest part, and this part will have everything in the middle of the quotes. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good regular expression to match string literals are:

```
["]([^"]|\\(.|\n))*["]
["]([^"\n]|\\(.|\n))*["]
```

The first one fails on multiline strings; the second one accepts them. In both cases, unmatched quotation mark won't be matched do you'll need to deal with those erroneous inputs with some other pattern. Both patterns accept backslash escapes (including backslash-escaped newlines) without making any attempt to interpret them. Most real-life lexical scanners will want to process backslash escape sequences in some fashion, often by turning them into the characters they represent. But that requires a different mechanism, which is out of scope for this question.

As you have discovered, the match includes the quotation marks, so you will want to remove them. Since you normally must make a copy of the matched token (since the contents of `yytext` will be overwritten the next time the scanner is called), that can easily be done by simply copying the part of the match you are interested in.

Remember that `yyleng` is the length of the token. Consequently the substring you want starts at `yytext + 1` (to skip over the opening quote) and continues for `yyleng - 2` characters (to not include either quote):

```
["]([^"]|\\(.|\n))*["]  {
          yylval.str = malloc(yyleng -1);
          memcpy(yylval.str, yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);
          yylval.str[yyleng - 2] = 0;
        }
```

There are other ways to write that, of course, but they will all be similar.

Comment: Many thanks! I have consulted a lot of relevant information, but I have not used regex to directly solve this problem... So I began to hesitate to think that this seems to be a small flaw in lex itself, this pair of double quotes used for recognition seems to Will inevitably be attached to the results. For the time being, I only have a shallow understanding of regex. You have given a way to modify the results with subsequent code. This kind of pointing is really broadening my thinking. Thank you again! This has a big and very advanced help for me.☀️